# Start up scripts with google compute engine in node js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Im a novice to google cloud compute api in node 
im using this library
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/index.html
im authenticated and can make API requests that is all set up
all im trying to do is make a start up script that will download from this URL 
http://eve-robotics.com/release/EveAIO_setup.exe and places the folder on the desktop
i have this but im 100% sure this is way off based on some articles and docs i am seeing but i know nothing ab bash, start up scripts

this is what i have

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-c')
 async function createVM(){
     vmName = 'start-script-trial3'
    //  const [vm, operation] = await zone.createVM(vmName, {


    //  })
    const config = {
        os: 'windows',
        http: true,
         metadata: {
            items: [
              {
                key: 'startup-script',
                value: `curl http://eve-robotics.com/release/EveAIO_setup.exe --output Eve`,
              },
            ]}
}
    const vm = zone.vm(vmName)
    const [gas, operation] = await vm.create(config)
    console.log(operation.id)
 }
createVM()
```

Comment: do you have a error?

Comment: Is curl a tool/command available on a virgin Windows install?  If not, is there a built in command to download a file via an HTTP request and save it as a file?  What is you run the curl command from a CMD prompt ... does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in bash:

I made a 'bat' script for windows:

```
      @ECHO OFF
      curl http://eve-robotics.com/release/EveAIO_setup.exe --output C:\Users\Eve
```

I copied the script to GCS:

```
     gsutil cp file.bat  gs://my-bucket/
```

Then I run the gcloud command:

```
     gcloud compute instances create example-windows-instance --scopes storage-ro  --image-family=windows-1803-core --image-project=windows-cloud --metadata windows-startup-script-url=gs://marian-b/file.bat --zone=europe-west1-c
```

Comment: is it possible if i just pass the script you wrote in the value in the metadata itself?

Comment: ```
    const config = {
        http: true,
        https:true,
        disks: [
          windowsDisk
        ],
         metadata: {
            items: [
              {
                key: 'startup-script',
                value: '@ECHO OFF
                curl http://eve-robotics.com/release/EveAIO_setup.exe --output C:\Users\Desktop\Eve',
              },
            ]},
}```

Comment: sorry about the format im new to stackoverflow and it wasnt formatting correctly but passing the config like that to create the VM